# Display text above image on hover, in a slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

Just as the title states, I have a slide show, and would like the text "SOLD OUT" to display if I hover one of the images. The solutions I have found so far state I should use a wrap around the images, but whenever I use `<div>` tags to wrap an image in the slideshow, the slider stops working. I need 2 effects to occur once I hover the image: make an overlaying white background with low opacity, along with solid text stating "SOLD OUT". I am using the "content" freature in CSS, but I can not get it to come up.

```css
.slide-container {
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}
#id1:hover{
    background: white;
    opacity: .3;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 10000;  
    font-weight: bolder;
    content: "SOLD OUT";
}
```

```html
              <div class="slide-container">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/350" id="id1"/>
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/350" />
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/350" />
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/350" />
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/350" />
              </div>
```

Comment: The `content` property can only be used on `::before`/`::after` CSS pseudo-classes, which do not work on self-closing elements like `img`, `input` or `button`. You would need to wrap your `<img>` elements in another type of element to style them properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom attribute to the images and display it on hover using JavaScript.

```js
$(".hover-container").hide();
    
$('.slide-container img').hover(function () {
  $(".hover-container").show();
  $(".hover-container").text($(this).data('text') || '');
},function () {
  $(".hover-container").hide();
});
```

```css
.slide-container {
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}

.hover-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350" data-text="SOLD OUT 1"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350" data-text="SOLD OUT 2"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350" data-text="SOLD OUT 3"/>
  <div class="hover-container"></div>
</div>
```